# Фильтрация по массивам в ячейке excel с помощью pandas

Tags: python, массивы, pandas, excel

Задача заключается в том, что мне необходимо получать необходимые значения из столбца 1 основываясь на значениях столбца 2:
[image: Столбец 1 и столбец 2]

В данном случае мне необходимы значения из столбца 1, в которых в столбце 2 есть текст enable. Я реализую это следующим образом: `klap = df.loc[df["Ограничения"] == "enable"]`

Но когда я сталкиваюсь с примерами столбца, где в одной ячейке находится массив значений
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Я не понимаю что с этим делать. В данной случае, я хочу получить 1 столбец, где во втором есть значение "UVS". Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сделать так, используя `str.contains` и регулярное выражение:

```
df.loc[df["Ограничения"].str.contains(r'\bUVS\b', regex=True)]
```

Обратите внимание, что в строке с регулярным выражении используется формат `raw-string` (`r` перед строкой), чтобы бэкслэши `\` не обрабатывались как признаки спецсимволов, а попали в регулярное выражение "как есть", и используется маска `\b`, обозначающая границу слова.

Comment: При использовании данного решения в параметры пришлось дописать na=False, т.к выскакивала ошибка. Вопрос правда не до конца решён. Дело в том, что помимо UVS, есть ещё и UVSE.
В предложенном вами методе, если он встречает слово "UVSE", то принимает логическое значение True, т.к в UVSE содержится UVS.
Как можно этого избегать?

Comment: Хм, а вы в точности регулярку как у меня написали? `\b` - это граница слова, не должно быть такого срабатывания как вы пишете

Comment: Да. действительно была ошибка в символе. Прошу прощения.